# alternative way to include external sylesheets rather than @import?

Tags: css, import, stylesheet

So, documentation has shown that using @import on stylesheets is a bit slower, and plus it makes extra server calls.

Example:

```
@import url('narf.css');
```

Well, I HATE using one giant stylesheet, it is messy. I am a neat freak when it comes to my code. hahaha.

Anyway, I use dreamweaver for my design, but it does not "respond" to using regular includes to include another stylesheet (even with boilerplate).  Basically, you cannot access the "included" styles when you are designing.

These do not work when using Dreamweaver (although they may work on the server).

```
<!--#include file="narf.css" -->
<?php include('narf.css'); ?>
```

So, I ask, are there any other alternatives to actually USE the styles during the design process and still keep the server requests down?  I appreciate any insight you may be able to share.

Thank you again overflow community!

Answer (score 0):

You could just have multiple stylesheets, and concatenate your stylesheets for production, that way you can separate your stylesheets, and keep the server requests to a minimum.

Comment: I was thinking about that as well.  The problem I have found though, is  we made DAILY changes to our code and css. It's quite the pain to concatenate every single time. And using the boilerplate style, you MUST use the include way or else it won't work.